# WPF How to have converter react to changes in multiple fields

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, converters

My MainWindow's data context is a class ViewModel:

ViewModel:

- Location
- IsUnsavedChanges

I want MainWindow's title to be based on a converter. The converter should receive the ViewModel class, but it should be invoked whenever Location or IsUnsavedChanges changes.

What technique can I use when I want a converter to be bound to an object, but also react to changes in that object's fields?

Currently I can bind to the Location field within the data context, and that works fine. See below from MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <my:MainWindowTitleConverter x:Key="titleConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.Title>
    <Binding Converter="{StaticResource titleConverter}" Path="Location"/>
</Window.Title>
```

However, if I just bind to the data context (specifying no Path) then it gets invoked when the data context changes but not when Location or IsUnsavedChanges changes.

I could get around this by just adding a new Title field in ViewModel and notifying it as changed whenever the Location, IsUnsavedChanges, etc. fields change, but I feel that it is a bit hacky.

Comment: look into multibinding and `IMultiValueConverter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, with [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can bind window `Title` to react to multiple properties, for example :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <my:MultiValueTitleConverter x:Key="titleConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Title>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
        <Binding Path="Location" />
        <Binding Path="IsUnsavedChanges" />
    </MultiBinding>
</Window.Title>
```

In addition, you need to have converter class that implements `IMultiValueConverter` for use with multibinding. For example :

```
public class MultiValueTitleConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length > 1 && values[0] is string && values[1] is bool)
        {
            var location= values[0] as string;
            var isUnsavedChanges= values[1] as bool;
            return "some value based on two values above";
        } 
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! After finding that I can bind to any number of objects similar to your example, I chose to not bind to the ViewModel and instead bind to a bunch of its fields directly.

Comment: agree, with multibinding passing ViewModel directly isn't necessary anymore. Updated converter sample in this answer a bit.